# Find the number of pairs in an array whose difference is K?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, time-complexity

So basically what I'm trying to do is

```
static int NumdiffExponential(int[] arr, int K)
{
    return (from i in arr
            from j in arr
            where (j - i) == K
            select 1).Count();
}
```

except in linear time, preferably with a single LINQ query and in a way that is compact, readable and micro-optimal. So what I came up with is the attempt

```
static int NumdiffLinear(int[] arr, int K)
{
    var counters = 
        arr
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
    return 
        counters
        .Keys
        .Aggregate(
            0, 
            (total, i) => total + counters[i] * (counters.ContainsKey(K - i) ? counters[K - i] : 0)
        ); 
}
```

which keeps coming out as `0` and I can't figure out why.

Let me explain how I think it works. If we have `arr={1,1,1,2,3,3,5}` and `K=2`, then the `counter` is like

```
1->3, 2->1, 3->2, 5->1
```

Let `count = 0`.

I take the key `1` and see that `1-K=-1` is not a key in `counter` and therefore `count =`0 still. Same with the key `2`.

For the key `3` we have `3-K=1` which is a key in `counter`. There are `3` occurrences of the key `1` (i.e. `counter[3]=1` and 2 occurrences of the key `2`. Therefore `count = 3*2 = 6` because of the pairs (1,3),(1,3),(1,3),(1,3),(1,3),(1,3),(1,3) which can be formed.

By the same logic as above, we add one more to `count` because of the pair (3,5). So the answer is `count = 7`.

Anything wrong with my algorithm or the implementation of it?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the array is already sorted, as in your example?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix-up the your solution as follows,

```
public int NumdiffLinear(int[] arr, int K)
        {
            var dupsDictionary =
                arr
                    .GroupBy(i => i)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());


            return dupsDictionary.Keys.Aggregate(
                0,
                (total, i) =>
                    total +
                    dupsDictionary.Keys.Where(key => i - key == K)
                        .Sum(key => dupsDictionary[key]*dupsDictionary[i]));
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

More readable and much more compact:

```
static int NumdiffLinear(int[] arr, int K)
{
    return arr.SelectMany(v => arr, (a, b) => new { a, b })
                .Where(s => s.b - s.a == K)
                .Count();
}
```

Here is a linear one with the same principle:

```
static int NumdiffLinear(int[] arr, int K)
{
    int n = 1;
    return arr.Select(value => new { value, index = n++ }) //Get number and index
                .SelectMany(indexValue => arr.Skip(indexValue.index), (a, b) => new { a = a.value, b }) //Project it with the next elements in the array
                .Where(s => s.a - s.b == K) //Do the math
                .Count();
}
```

Comment: SelectMany is still `O(n^2)`. not any faster than OPs first solution. (so its not linear)

Comment: Check the new one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
(total, i) => total + counters[i] * (counters.ContainsKey(K - i) ? counters[K - i] : 0)
```

by

```
(total, i) => total + counters[i] * (counters.ContainsKey(i-K) ? counters[i-K] : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add instead of subtract. for example you know you have `key = 1` and `K = 2`. then you have to check if `key = (1+2)` exist or not.

In your O(n^2) algorithm you check `J - I == K`. now assume you have only `I` and `K`. Simple math just do `J = K + I` if the condition were true then `J` should exist.

```
(total, i) => total + counters[i] * (counters.ContainsKey(K + i) ? counters[K + i] : 0)
```